# Comparing y-coordinate in tuple list with a condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list :

```
 a = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5), (6, 7), (5,90)]
 # Stores list of x,y coordinates
```

and a list:

```
 b = [(1, 2), (10, 1), (3, 10), (4, 9), (10,9)]
```

and a variable z = 90

Now, I want to replace in `a` where it has y coordinate in `a` >= of , `b` with y coordinate + 2, with a condition that `y` coordinate should never exceed some value `z`. So, `y +2` should never exceed `z`.

Since here `a` has an equivalent or greater of `b` in:

```
[(1,2), (3,4), (5,90)]
```

I want to replace in `a` such that it becomes:

```
a = [(1,4), (3,6), (4,5), (6,7), (5,90)]
```

How could I do this?

I know there exists a method with numpy such that:

```
np.where(a >= b) , do something;
```

but not sure how could I use it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have lists instead of tuples

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 5], [6, 7], [5,90]]
b = [[1, 2], [10, 1], [3, 1], [4, 9], [10,9]]
z = 90
for n,na in enumerate(a):
    if na[1] >= b[n][1]:
        if na[1] < 89:
            a[n][1] += 2
print(a)
```

#### Tuples

This is the code if you need to have output in tuple

```
a = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5), (6, 7), (5,90)]
b = [(1, 2), (10, 1), (3, 10), (4, 9), (10,9)]

a1 = [list(x) for x in a]
b1 = [list(x) for x in b]
z = 90
for n,na in enumerate(a1):
    if na[1] >= b1[n][1]:
        if na[1] < 89:
            a1[n][1] += 2
        elif na[1] == 89:
            a1[n][1] = 90

a = [tuple(x) for x in a1]

print(a)
```

> [(1, 4), (3, 6), (4, 5), (6, 7), (5, 90)]

#### In case you want numpy to do it

```
import numpy as np
a = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5), (6, 7), (5,90)]
b = [(1, 2), (10, 1), (3, 10), (4, 9), (10,9)]
a, b = np.array(a), np.array(b)

z = 90

second_element = np.s_[:, 1]
is_bigger = a[second_element] >= b[second_element]
a[second_element][is_bigger] = np.clip(a[second_element][is_bigger] + 2,
                    a_min=None, a_max=z)
a = [tuple(x) for x in a]
print(a)
```

> output
>
> [(1, 4), (3, 6), (4, 5), (6, 7), (5, 90)]

Comment: Can't have a list.

Comment: Also, is there a way with numpy?

Answer (score 1):

Tuples in Python are immutable and cannot be changed. You should create a new list of new tuples, say, with list comprehension:

```
a = [(ax, min(z, ay + 2 if ay >= by else ay))
        for ((ax, ay), (_, by)) in zip(a, b)]
```

Numpy is useless in your case because it does not work with tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5), (6, 7), (5,90)]
b = [(1, 2), (10, 1), (3, 10), (4, 9), (10, 9)]
z=90
c=[]
for index, val in enumerate(a):
    try:
        y = (val[1]+2 if index < len(b) and len(b[index])>1 and val[1]>=b[index][1] and val[1]+2 <= z else val[1])
        c.append((val[0],y))
    except:
        print("Provide proper inputs.")
a = c

print(a)
```

Or using list comprehension:

```
c = [(a[index][0],(a[index][1]+2 if a[index][1] >= b[index][1] and a[index][1]+2 < z else a[index][1])) for index in range(len(a))]
a=c
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cast the lists as arrays to utilize NumPy. This will arrange the xs and ys as columns. This makes it easy to use slices (`np.s_`) to form masks to target the conditions. Then you can utilize `np.clip` to restrict the data to remain within a certain range. Doing so this way allows you to leverage vectorized operations for fast manipulations if your data is large.

```
>>> a = np.array([(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5), (6, 7), (5,90)])
>>> b = np.array([(1, 2), (10, 1), (3, 10), (4, 9), (10,9)])
>>> z = 90

>>> ys = np.s_[:, 1]
>>> mask = a[ys] >= b[ys]
>>> a[ys][mask] = np.clip(a[ys][mask] + 2, a_min=None, a_max=z)
>>> a
array([[ 1,  4],
       [ 3,  6],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 5, 90]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `numpy` by

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 5], [6, 7], [5,90]]
b = [[1, 2], [10, 1], [3, 1], [4, 9], [10,9]]
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)

mask_ab = a[:, 1] >= b[:, 1]
mask_smaller = a[:, 1] < 89
mask = np.logical_and(mask_ab, mask_smaller)
a[mask, 1] += 2
```